# How to properly change wwwroot to another directory

Tags: asp.net-core, static-files, wwwroot

What is the proper way to reconfigure the default "wwwroot" folder to something else or, additionally, default to an inner folder?

My current structure has wwwroot/dist as the root folder.  I added the line

```
.UseWebRoot("wwwroot/dist")
```

to the WebHostBuilder() configuration and this works.  However, Intellisense is now complaining throughout the application for my file paths.  It's still expecting "wwwroot" to be the root folder.

Comment: You got a bad habit of forcing tags into the question title. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging on how to correctly use tags

Comment: Is Intellisense the only issue here? Is `UseWebRoot` otherwise working fine? If so, I'm guessing this is a bug in Visual Studio.